# How To Use ngModel For Two-Way Binding In Angular 13

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms, ngmodel

I am simply trying to take the user input from the input element and save it in a variable.

This is what my component typescript looks like:

```
export class MyComponent {
 userInput: string = '';
}
```

This is what my html looks like:

```
<input name="userInput" [(ngModel)]="userInput">
```

And this is what my app.module.ts looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MyComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    FormsModule
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am getting this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '_rawValidators')
```

I've searched all over but can't find anything for this particular error. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found out my particular issue involved my input element being inside a different form element by accident. Moving the input element outside of the form element fixed this issue.